# how do I make a post request in FastApi to edit data in angular Ag-grid table and save the change in snowflake database?

Tags: angular, post, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, fastapi, ag-grid-angular

I have set a aggrid table in Angular with columns from a json in the database. I am trying to edit the aggrid table and have those new changes save to the database using a post request.

I am new to both angular and pthon.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AG Grid Events](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-events/), you can take advantage of the editing event to send the new data to your api via POST request.